# Programmatically turn off GPS on Flutter

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I need to close the GPS that opened for the Flutter app .
this work is possible ?

Comment: I believe it's not possible

Comment: We can't interfere with native android Or ios setting with our user interaction as that will be a security concern let say some application can implicitly change some setting (in your case gps) then that application can restrict user to get location in case of lost device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we can only guide the user to the device settings page to ask him to manually turn off the device GPS.